# Page Update in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am using facebook sdk in Android. I can take friendlist information by using:

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "name, picture,location");
    Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", params,new FriendsRequestListener());
```

How can I get page posts like statuses, image, photos, videos etc. ?

Comment: Your question is not clear . Are you trying to get friend wall posts or page wall posts?

Comment: Please refer Hackbook for Android